# displot 'FacetGrid' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet-grid, displot

I wrote the following code in order to plot a 2x2 displot with seaborn:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Re'    : x,
     'n'     : y,
     'Type'  : tp,
     'tg'    : tg,
     'gt'    : gt
    })

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='gt', col='tg', margin_titles=False, height=2.5, aspect=1.65)
g.map(sns.displot(df, x='Re', y='n', hue='Type', kind='kde',log_scale=True, palette=customPalette, fit_reg=False, x_jitter=.1))
```

However I get this error that I cannot fix:

```
func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)

TypeError: 'FacetGrid' object is not callable
```

The x, y, tp, tg and gt imported in the df are lists.

Does anyone have any clue what I might do to fix this?
Thank you in advance! :)

*This is how the df looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6J9c.png

Comment: no I don't have something like this... Earlier in the code I just read the lists, that's why I dind't provide that part. Sorry

Comment: Then please provide a [mre] and the complete error traceback

Comment: @JohanC Sure! sns.displot without g.map works properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `sns.displot`is already a `FacetGrid`.  You can't give it as a parameter to `g.map`. Moreover, the parameter to `g.map` is meant to be a function without evaluating it (so, without brackets, and the parameters given as parameters to `g.map`). See the examples at [Seaborn's FacetGrid page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).

The most common `FacetGrid` parameters (such as `row`, `col`, `height`and `aspect`) can be provided directly to `sns.displot()`. Less common parameters go into `facet_kws=...`.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Re': np.random.rand(100),
                   'n': np.random.rand(100),
                   'Type': np.random.choice([*'abc'], 100),
                   'tg': np.random.choice(['ETG', 'LTG'], 100),
                   'gt': np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)})
g = sns.displot(df, x='Re', y='n', hue='Type', kind='kde',
                row='gt', col='tg', height=2.5, aspect=1.65,
                log_scale=True, palette='hls',
                facet_kws={'margin_titles': False})
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot with row= and col=]

To directly work with `FacetGrid` (not recommended), you could create a similar plot with:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='gt', col='tg', hue='Type', palette='hls',
                  margin_titles=False, height=2.5, aspect=1.65)
g.map_dataframe(sns.kdeplot,
                x='Re', y='n',
                log_scale=True)
g.add_legend()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)